# Vertically align div in a parent of variable height

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have a wrapper, whose height is variable (depending on the content in the left box). I want the `button` inside this wrapper to be vertically aligned inside the right side box.

I am not able to get it to work, though I have tried quite a few things, including [css-tricks' post on centering](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/), which I've put under comments. I tried tinkering with `flexbox` too, but didn't work.

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 20em;
    margin: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.left {
    float: left;
    width: 70%;
}
.right {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden; /* to induce block formatting context */
}
.button {
    width: 3em;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    margin: 0 auto;

    /*
    // The below didn't work! the `button` vanishes.
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">Every person is worth just as much as the things they busy themselves with.</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="button">button</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary issue here is that you need the left and right divs to have the same height automagically. Other than javascript, only flexbox and css tables allow for that. So...

**Flexbox** *can* do that.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 20em;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}
.left {
  flex: 0 0 70%;
}
.right {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
.button {
  width: 3em;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">Every person is worth just as much as the things they busy themselves with.</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="button">button</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

OR...**CSS Tables**

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 20em;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fixed;
}

.left {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 70%;
}

.right {
  display: table-cell;
  width: 30%;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}

.button {
  width: 3em;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">Every person is worth just as much as the things they busy themselves with.</div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="button">button</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Newbie question: please elaborate on why `flex: 0 0 70%;` for left and `flex: 1;` for right - i'm a bit confused about grow/shrink.

Comment: `flex: 0 0 70%` just means a width of 70% that won't change. `flex:1` just means "grow as much as possible in the remaining space"..I could have put `flex: 0 0 30%` but `flex:1` was quicker.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `display:inline-block;` instead of `float left;` and don't forget to [remove extra spaces](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/) which is occurred by `display:inline-block;`.

```css
.wrapper {
    width: 20em;
    margin: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.left,
.right
{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:middle;
  }
.left {
    width: 70%;
}
.right {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden; /* to induce block formatting context */
  text-align:center;
  width:30%;
}
.button {
    width: 3em;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    margin: 0 auto;

    /*
    // The below didn't work! the `button` vanishes.
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    */
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">Every person is worth just as much as the things they busy themselves with.</div><div class="right">
    <div class="button">button</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. But this introduces a new problem of horizontal alignment of `button` within `right` (it can be seen by adding `background-color: #688dba;` to `left`

Comment: Give `text-align:center;` and `width:30%;` to `.right`. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This works if you're willing to use `calc`:

```
.button {
    width: 3em;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    margin: calc(50% - 0.5em) 0 calc(50% - 0.5em) 0;
```

There's a catch to it though: calc will not accept other parameters such as height of the button; so I have assumed it to be 1em(since you don't define the height).

Comment: This is very elegant (technically, the height will be known - line-height, padding and border etc.). I chose the other answer simply because it helped me understand the problem more accurately (of unequal heights for left and right). Thanks.

Comment: The other answer is, undoubtedly, more elegant than mine.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this styles workout,

```
.wrapper{
  width: 20em;
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
.left{
  float: left;
  width: 15em;
}
.right{
  width: 5em;
  float: right;
}

.button {
  width: 3em;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  margin: 1em;
}
```

Comment: `margin-top:1em` doesn't quite address the problem of variable heights